# Questions about eliminating oscillation and noise in a load cell system

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, adc, ltspice, passive-filter

I'd like to ask you for your expertise on a challenge I'm facing as part of an electronics project.

A crucial part of this project is the integration of a force sensor, whose variation in resistance (represented by the resistor R on the diagram) is directly linked to the force applied. This variation in resistance induces a fluctuation in voltage, from which I can accurately deduce the force exerted.

[image]

However, to ensure accurate force measurement, it is essential to minimise the noise in the signal. The more accurate the signal, the less likely measurement errors are to occur.

In our setup, the voltage from the force transducer is then passed to the internal analogue-to-digital converters (ADCs) of a microcontroller (STM32). However, I have encountered a problem: at the output of the first operational amplifier (AOP/ Vs1), the signal exhibits undesirable oscillations, as illustrated in the curve provided.

[image]
[image]

In order to attenuate these oscillations, I simulated an RC filter with a cut-off frequency of 3 Hz.

[image]
[image]

So I made the following electrical diagram. However, the oscillation persists. Although the amplitude of the oscillation appears to be decreasing, the noise remains, as indicated by a new spectral analysis.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I turn to you with the following questions:

How can I really eliminate this oscillation and obtain a smooth signal?
Is it possible to eliminate this noise completely, or are there techniques to reduce it as much as possible?
Is the use of a tracking PDO really necessary in this configuration, or are there more effective alternatives?
Is the noise related to the breadboard tests?

I would be very grateful for any suggestions, advice or shared experience on this subject.

Thank you in advance for your invaluable help.

All the best,

Comment: Did you use any bypass capacitor (0.1->1 uF) directly on power supply of opamps? What is Vout? Don't need also an offset  voltage at "-input" ? The low pin of R should also be wired to midpoint R3/R4.

Comment: How fast transient response from your load cell do you need to measure?

Comment: you should see first this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSdEwA7s8bE https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6ogr.png

Comment: @Antonio51 No, I didn't use a bypass capacitor. I didn't think of it. I'll give it a try.
Vout is a 5V supply. 
No, I don't need to. The output voltage is Vs1=Vout/2*(1+R2/R1). When I press on the pressure sensor, I can see the voltage changing according to the pressure applied, what I would like is to reduce the noise as much as possible to improve accuracy.
Why should I connect the R3/R4 resistor?

Comment: @winny response time is 5uS

Comment: Is the response time 5 us (note lowercase s for second) or do you need 5 us? With 3 Hz low-pass, you won’t be close. I’m asking because heavy low-pass is the first step to get rid of high frequency noise. You need bypass capacitors and low noise on your ground and supply to have low noise output.